# Factorize matrix determinant

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, factoring, diagonalization

When trying to diagonalize a matrix, say :

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  0 & 2 & -1 \\
  3 & -2 & 0 \\
  -2 & 2 & 1
 \end{matrix}\right)$$

to find the eigenvalues, I have to find the determinant :

$$\left|\begin{matrix}
  -\lambda & 2 & -1 \\
  3 & -2-\lambda & 0 \\
  -2 & 2 & 1-\lambda
 \end{matrix}\right|$$

I often see people doing some voodoo manipulations on lines and columns to end up with an already factorized polynomial.
So how do they do this exactly ?

I've looked at some examples but the manipulations seem random to me, I can't figure out a pattern except maybe trying to make zeros appear on the first line...
I need some advice on how to look at this.

Comment: i think there is no specific way to do this..

Comment: expanding the determinant blindly may give u the factor...

Comment: For what it's worth, the rows always add up to $1$ so $1$ is an eigenvalue. The trace is negative, so there is at least a negative eigenvalue.

Comment: You can add/subtract rows without changing the value of the determinant. You can exchange neighbouring columns and change the sign of the determinant. With these two things in mind the strategy is then to create 0's in the determinant, especially in the top row, so that it evaluates more easily. If you get a common expression across a row that will be a factor of your determinant too. Try subtracting the 3rd row from the first.

Comment: For a $3\times3$ determinant, you have also the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). It won't give you the factors stright away, but it's nevertheless useful to find the determinant quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left|\begin{matrix}
  -\lambda & 2 & -1 \\
  3 & -2-\lambda & 0 \\
  -2 & 2 & 1-\lambda
 \end{matrix}\right| = 
\left|\begin{matrix}
  1-\lambda & 2 & -1 \\
  1-\lambda & -2-\lambda & 0 \\
  1-\lambda & 2 & 1-\lambda
 \end{matrix}\right|$ with $C_1 \leftarrow C_1 + C_2 + C_3$.

$ = (1-\lambda)\left|\begin{matrix}
  1 & 2 & -1 \\
  1 & -2-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 1-\lambda
 \end{matrix}\right|$
$ = (1-\lambda)\left|\begin{matrix}
  1 & 2 & -1 \\
  0 & -4-\lambda & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 2-\lambda
 \end{matrix}\right|$

with $L_2 \leftarrow -L_1 + L_2$ and $L_3 \leftarrow -L_1 + L_3$.

$ = (1-\lambda)(-4-\lambda)(2-\lambda)$ because the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the elements of its diagonal.

The eigenvalues are then $-4, 1$ and $2$.

Note that even without the triangular matrix trick, we could have transformed the last $3\times3$ determinant in a $2\times2$ because the first column has $0$ everywhere except once. Then we could have developped it and compute the roots with a classical second degree polynomial problem.